# Svelte gives error "process is not defined"

Tags: svelte

I am creating a Svelte app and I want to access variables from .env. If I place the line

```
let dev = process.env.DEV_MODE;
```

in my app I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Am I missing some package?

**.env**

```
DEV_MODE=true;
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "svelte-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rollup -c",
        "dev": "rollup -c -w",
        "start": "sirv public --no-clear",
        "debug": "netlify dev"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^17.0.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^11.0.0",
        "rollup": "^2.3.4",
        "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
        "rollup-plugin-inject-process-env": "^1.3.1",
        "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
        "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.1.0",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
        "svelte": "^3.49.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "faunadb": "^4.5.4",
        "netlify-cli": "^10.10.2",
        "netlify-lambda": "^2.0.15",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "sirv-cli": "^1.0.11"
    }
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            }
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process` is a NodeJS variable which will not be available in the browser. You have a plugin [`rollup-plugin-inject-process-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-inject-process-env) installed but you are not using it. [Set it up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-inject-process-env#usage) with the respective variables first.

Comment: For the benefit of others looking for this solution, add "injectProcessEnv({DEV_MODE: process.env.DEV_MODE,})" to the "plugins" section of rollup.config.js after you have added the import